# Script that spits our random command problem [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, command, powershell-cmdlet

```
$k = get-command -all | measure | select-object count
$result = $k -replace "[{}@Count=]", ""
$rand = get-random -maximum $result
$minrand = $rand - 1
get-command -all -totalcount $rand | Select-Object -skip $minrand
```

This is supposed to spit out ONE command, alias, cmdlet whatever. I would hope that this would be useful for learning PowerShell.

The issue is that it spits out the same command over and over.

Comment: Pipe `Get-Random` to `Get-Command` --> `Get-Command | Get-Random`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very complicated. You can just do this:

```
$Commands = Get-Command -All
```

Then keep running this:

```
Get-Random $Commands
```

To get a random different command each time.

---

Regarding your code, you don't ever need to do this (which would return a string result):

```
$k = get-command -all | measure | select-object count
$result = $k -replace "[{}@Count=]", ""
```

You should instead be doing something like this:

```
$k = get-command -all | measure | select-object count
$result = $k.count
```

Via which you're accessing the count property of `$k` and getting its integer value.

PowerShell returns objects with properties, so while you often see string based results in the console, when you want to manipulate those results you should work with the object properties. Piping an object to `Get-Member` is a good way to discover the properties of an object (as well as its methods etc.). For example try:

```
$k | Get-Member
```

To see its properties.

`Get-Help`, `Get-Command` and `Get-Member` are 3 of the most useful tools for discovering and learning PowerShell from within the shell.